# Mysql replaces special characters like +

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hope you are doing well,
Recently I am trying to store html code generated by summernote WYSIWYG editor to the MySQL database which most of the times may contain images within it, the problem is that MySQL replaces some characters like '+' with white-space, I have tried `addslashes()`, `mysql_real_escape_string()` functions of `PHP` but it didn't work, the data type I used in MySQL table is TEXT.
Anybody have a solution or idea, please help.
Thanks.

**JavaScript Function to upload data:**

```
function saveData(){
        var dt = $("#summernote").summernote('code');
        $.ajax({
            url: "save_data.php",
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            data: 'editor_content=' + dt,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#loaded").html("Success");
            }
        });
    }
```

**JavaScript Function to download data:**

```
function loadData(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: "get_data.php",
            type: 'post',
            data: 'id=' + id,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#loaded").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

**PHP to Save data to database:**

```
<?php

    $data = $_POST['editor_content'];
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=richtext', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO text (data) VALUES (?)");
    $sth->execute(array($data));
    echo $data;
?/
**PH
```

P to retrieve data from database:**

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=richtext', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM text WHERE id = ?");
    $sth->execute(array($id));
    print_r($sth->fetch());


?>
```

**Real Code:**

```
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" data-filename="_Male_Profile_Round_Circle_Users-128.png" style="width: 128px;"></p>
```

**Stored in DB:**

```
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAARHUlEQVR42u1deZAcVRnPJJtks7tsABMCIYKFJVLEkiMccbPZ7n6ve2Z3szvTx0wiBQUBSZSIVV6xSkorBQjikT wQA5RUMKhhMNCKBWJCggpEFAOFZUyApHiJuFYTCD6fd2zm97ZnunX53w9zFS92mSz frt 71 x/f9vt83bVr70/5E aiqnIM23dVybXutY8/vYTNqW9te69jzm2Ud0Ga6WkfY2da2R8ueyMPwAbNcbWbEzsdqb2CofICsmqqimmfB12/JXL9RVq0tCjMfk5i1XWLGDkU1xuDre9iqf96B/4Y/gz8Lf75O4eYFklpeo2gGGxiyFlD9feO0J/Kw2dA6XW12xM5HsrdkydqZimL1AVjrFdW6FUB/Dtr/JjcrQptkC23/HL6/nvPyJyRJ6sj6 AV9GD5gjqt1Rux8KHuMjS4AwNc6gFs764AVN/hT7OGqIXPrFlglzuwfLM/PyviFeRieJrugdbsa/n16WvYGB0/uhUFfI3Hrbhj4d4OCFTf4ta3ap7tkZn6qr6 4D7Xxiwo PqDH1bojdl7YnqRax8nc/BEM8JtxgRU3 FOb8QZ8vUrJV5Y0e/ziAr/X1Xoidr5HwF4OltaSrBr3JA9WsvYkbt4Hh9CVstw/N8Xxi23P73I9cPwXiNL5cTtz69mTmKlLqvHnZoCVqD1mPMa00qqkxy8oxn4HjO6aGZdY5yW10g/XrwdJgJWkPWY9ABN8aTPBr I7w/P/u64Wc2r2mkTAZ6x8MAzMjSTBSs7eHvjepuUF46Amgd/hOQFcToVO1wToTgj8HFzlznKcMu8r8PeeD1TjdbzO4likCP64p9BzAnRUPUnjE6ArCfAVxTwUrnO/zxJYSdqzPY SsSgF8Ge7PIUzJp0Bqt Y6ZoAnYmAr1on2TO/Df7kxs1XmVauJAT dBemExPA61AwPgGiuCc9O6/rpU4YlMtbAqwE7cH19xJZHt4/ZvC7XJ5CxLfD64dmuPaHXLxv/ugihRtb2 AL2mPmVkUZPTwm8MfPceMTYCq rgnQETf4jJlHwy/2bBv8YPYk1XyGseIJMTiNelwTwHtld02AWMGXuJEPfspvg793EhivwwukRMCj1zUBOhs6fiK6i6eAD/7wEsTU32mDH9WeMSZzY0VIPMYnQFeSUcKpy75WXgmd390GPy57xi4IiFkh8OhNOlDk ea3wU/CHk6C itBHTx6UgXf2fPby35y9owxrzNBEoGisKf9nW2wkrVnO9EUazEp8O17fvuql5o9IMlsk6TKgSTAtz18bSdP vaYdV cHsMIvn3i7l3wsUPg6Q74epHMyp9mmmEompUHpo7qboxZQxinABr5l ANuxIm9aMS09 lPJmAMXVFWuD31Avs0ARfH4Pv/xBAXb5hw4bpYSe7pq34kMJKZ8OkeJjqSgIT rSkwe/2uFs6IV2CUT3g3107UNAPjnuls1cIZv2d3GTnxmvL88VD0 YE5gjG84GJW0yUczcyMtKFTB5q2xzyCeqRShLhBMq8vI5U4ITpO2W1JKVFuIQB/x7BA SaVDiByFwJft9PdDD2MKZbKbNtc/Dc2yndHnA7FuQYRuMEUiNwyqp STOo1pJ00jyger9I6 pobkqUE4jUbUrgQw7Bi8uWjcxtFs9 6lbYdL/BnnqU81g4gTDjH6J1ADK/2swkCzszmVn/IeU0AqdcIpxA24FCiSzBjP9yrn g2Rk24CM4n5rHEG5oI3FzAnMonEDp6oPevWaDj/9P1kZPpOcuNh5BzGLjBGK HjXfuaxZn202 OP2oF/b6bGLjdHYOIHw9t9L7d4LnrmPUwDfmQDGzeRiBcy4NxZOIOfG8fScHsYuPIBRAB8bXEXPoxgrYHl9IDInEMUZqIVMIVr3FBXwXRxIeiFnrl8TiROIsixA8XqLWrwcZWKogO8ExkCkimZU9E1ZNntDB4SqQkwUyRKbqYBvH5Lz5hF0ySbl00NPAFtbjyBTBrJmfkwFfOdnKodQZRoBUfdXocBHzpkjokiPJoXnEirg42d5vvRBwjSz3Ri3CP72A32KLEeOG9dSAd/eKhX9w6Q5htw6I/j r5q30SVImrdRAd9eLbXK0cQJpjcFGgA7yOFo3dFkxwIjlgr41bMSp8wuRq5AIFnbydcagtRobv2LCviOr8Q6jTq1HMS4Tghy/VtPmRePsqyFQn4OBfCrK8D51PMK4OD8RWEPsLP/006yUNXikRTAdw7M5pXUk0ogoHezMCdQUvXtpDNsmL5teLiwHwXwq1tAiXw6GTP LcQJzOdLC4gu 6/YitwguSprej8V8CcIM6rxeWQHwcuzA4mqFF8eVS3v68sJrFbaINd5CP9 jMqe72cPJsFWiisnnFUUX04gllkhqbotFRZmAXyy/ADHxlpfTiDW2CGZCKkNL84C DY/gJt3UuQHQDLphb6cQCywRJLc4CRB0gcf6gLsZQqT4wdc78sJhOXrtyR18yCqRR18RylFL5DVI2D6Fl9OoDj7N/17L8jQSJTBX7361I5gNQ9Svjoy81FfTqBdO48ouQGoYP9ElhJF8G1mEDe/RrxYxTP PADq v3M iUlQqhLLGOlN3 C0PiBWopAGNgYo6 hY96 dGl5DhXwq8Gg3aTBt51p1lsiK8B7tMGfcGo8WFtkIW3wFUWaBZHJ72ZFgAo9qTFNABq bjgTPNzcPd/6RpbUx4QmgP8WQCzQoZQ/2gzwK5XKLOjrS5mqUSS4BezIlG4ecBeaQgVn5U9mTndQ5BAI9KHnMiWayKzHm8EMCqaVQGT8hK6BnlU7qStw6qNpgl8Vlcyg4qidNh40GYS /CokZ96fYqAohwOZUbnZuwTOANZ1WdTejaqYKVzbWC2fmVWtYfBX/MSXEwgHhQuyKLyMglGSZC1MNAMIZNjwIJVZoWlunevLCYQZviarqttwfvmDJJ3WmQT4qDmMS2iWVcYlzVztywlkzFCyLLmOYWNNO6U79vQv1dqYeYl5xVrmzwmUVxyQeb19uBr6ScgEAR9YUudlHnzQECwUzHlCOoEQN362BYot7IYk0s9FAX9wcHA2POeGlihWwc1twjqBwGm7rRUqbaDvG1KiDo7w5m9ooUoltwjrBMIv/uVWKbPirrIVOOsXpGhapUwNU/X1wjqBqDfbMjV2NHMgbKwAtsLftUqNInCWLRPWCcRUYvLMIPGTb1/YWEHjCZChqzJUFRkc1LoD6QRiMmErVNeC28DSsIGi hMgc36SmwLrBIq7PGkPhsRL/WEDRd4TIHtOMnABrw7sHtU04wA7GTPje6DMS31hA0VTJ0AWPaTGrny vH84ncCGrs9sDAaoeR8fNko4eQJk0z0ON7o7IwhFWmdkfQ/kfOSosFHCvdfADFck5eVTQ08A0ArsmSwWla3BwAgh5/J rVQMIpBIJNzksNTdtCgfcCH IJPgq YLVaZQaH4AYyvmK2rperCzK5uxEfPyaVE/EB08NjPgw30Xsps3ybxoVQsrx0IOwRKykFp9NmwJW8Jl/zQpDwD0CyNPAJv/DsUHCIO/E6pj3KDw4kpZHpqXNC0MSSHBq6Y24eVhxm9iAR/15uGtWkk3yqV/Ji1CKOQCzIBA2XcykQTCjcGo4E/UDnZED4zHyF71VP3SoaH8/CTBB1m6hfXV0x3OPXLuKCisYtqcKMaNwJ9UO5hppVXNSf8yngQdvq/Azw/D31 rL35gPAFl5E5MJAlEs05BlbIGGTcvjBNQ7ALTvAzJovo9zVIL83v7Q9cOBqbNA2lp28JSe1mtvKkjymw8X5cT6BzQrqrlAIQFH3IPj/OLCKJmAaqFe9lTtOIxcHjcCDaeT 3lcekoNwA/XO3gaph4T1Kdh3v3/ZhqXS/127majSyWuPl44yxY6x28vg5w65gwGj/wBuVhIH8hILu2xV28slEWMUxoCw9mCb88e3DS oAfvnZwVUZ2U7ydN962pVbzxlGiYBUK2kHO/dwU2UKeAKAuVDQr3z9Ynu/5piqjh8MWB7l  mWYPiXCr4MJdhEeCgPnFdjlZcxLYbV6M/7cP tqH/Cj1Q6e4MZP2otDOyleQkkVkfKvdd8s1VoVNEPX5jlw4x wLD8JN4insbBSwJT0bYpmsKgp6RigcSRl6vU/4LYJZxQM4DUYv2i1g2uCRGsiyrz8NS7qNk4gXEGCOWiCH0ixVjGsJN u7XfUxFS0F0/U0bs4VFy1g2s/ufp8Of/OI806dt6 Yi3Gyhj EyHwm/UuXu84Nw9LSozCPh9EqaGkWr9u5MeJXDvYO1BkLJqaJiXWeZHiBWEHF4HCN9W5LUQSU9guM ubimIemrQMjS02YY9liJVJtV5GH0Wd/sVTO7hunEArV0LIlLyCaVZJCzzhM2TNXIYyLrBa4Z38jcYCSnAogxrJeGCU1Ep/oz4moUcA55JN4ajvpt6gf9FrB/svX9YlcRYwSlbsYegIWS3KECwyYYUowVZUwNWo6jfIxb0tBbHHtOLJIZxGG3361xu5drBf5zHqBm/OVtHOM9U8m4K0GzV7spxfBGO3Wxh8ODjWFoLy6F9vpNrBop3HezTE358R6ny sqQNvrc98Fn8UfAq rTbp9Ggfz2Jgz/eGCuegC5cv6uUl8pnG/yqX4NbFwvk L2KzqQk xfed84tuaHMnIdYcRt81/hB/r6Pxs/bEHRaThL8vYdCYwVSkeuRN1BgqQ2 t71G1dodR5RZIA2 y1No1psEdsYuFFhqgz8F/PX1nFgIfu11jyz4rqDRcGPVUWOzqq5Y H4Hv6 vuA8A/NNGyz6FN78nzMOcM4FX4GiigMFTjI0OvF/BxxsRnOifanTgo7Dnd3vcLYUfBk6WI 0IWl2PIVCuuXlOoOLGWT/tOyrjX29wVrKves0 7U9wAms8S8EzbKTKgfC239fYY2g8ghT0Vgcfs5VhZfyTn5NH8J4fCfxAnMCog4EeQ6BHXeGjZ/8eJjNI0knzWg18TRs DFa6qwTC1hsFPHxR xeOExjHYMiseComcPhxApEs4cUZyBr4touX6 f7CW5gVM8nsBMn OE4gXENriTph4jo7yDbFqJz56hqZW7WwGescAgAfy5sbS LaPg2COnGDX40TmCMg5urMoteE6NxWRdDpu x1MEHl/hxsMJdtpdq1tit68PkiRv86JzAuAfX4RjaRNM9AkyePcDYhbQsY121ljAJ8AuFVftCn86C /o9ouxd Plr4Aq8IMXJGR8nMInBtSnndfMOPJUvxrB6GGoYeC2fSYOPz7RXMGbdAW/7WBDePufG8SmvTLFzAhPrPJwNRibr8QvLw/4F6dYoiIB1hLwYPWH7h7bwTo45C0AT z5M1r8F75/xkDsOkiL4yXACE 58DoJKo9X0qpC5dcbbGH20pV6Bww9tncJLp8AePSJrej/nxRMh//8oRSl9BJ1VmESCopJI0JR5eR3Y Jb9f20bYCtsijYcdkUSNRMCP1lOoMfDemu4aFE7D4eq0eUy0692OH2ZEWfYif4Mv8ykNMYvcU6ga5npqZlx0 O0J8tmrx0vh9Kxwat0pqPGhYJMuAWJ5jykOH7JcQKrxrtdrSuGA0tDe gpxOsTLNc/879GJqvAKTF9M0zM08NIsTVr/OKMFYz7C a4Dhm5NO1hfh6equE28AUAaHPjwFN0yXWwcSsKL6P2bkP51YyMXxTwZ7vulp0Rr44x2yvvCwc9CEWbayH cCF45DCR9G77QIfJn8irgyqaSE5xmvWW7ZTBf7MPfdZdttgD1NjBbQfyC/qrxRaI/r7x2hN1J85ytZkRO9 2R8SeaCBhpqt1ROx82x4ReyIPnFHb2vZax57IbJvuarm2vezb z KoJ8ZptPx1AAAAABJRU5ErkJg" data-filename="_Male_Profile_Round_Circle_Users-128.png" style="width: 128px;"><br></p>
```

Comment: Saved to Database:

Comment: Lost Some Special Characters

Comment: have you tried htmlspecialchars. that might work.

Comment: Including some code would help?  How do you store the data, what about the code to fetch it?

Comment: $data = $_POST['editor_content'];
    $encodedContent = base64_encode($data);
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=richtext', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO text (data) VALUES (?)");
    $sth->execute(array($encodedContent));
    echo $data;

Comment: I used for Saving data.

Comment: Alon Eitan, the variable '$data' in the code above contains all data to be stored into database, I have printed the variable ( variable Contains HTML code) to the screen it works well and displays image but, when it is stored to the database data gets modified by MySQL Engine (perhaps to prevent injection) and when I retrieve and print it it shows texts normally but images are corrupted.

Comment: Show the code that retrieves the image data (to the question)

Comment: I have Edited the Question, Thanks.

Comment: Encode image data while submitting in database and decode it while retrieving it using urlencode() and urldecode()

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your Javascript code, not on the server side.

```
data: 'editor_content=' + dt,
```

You're sending form data as a string, but not encoding it properly. The easiest fix will be to send it as an object, so that jQuery will encode it for you:

```
data: { editor_content: dt },
```

Comment: Well I have checked the data before storing to database (on server side), it is OK and working.